# How to start, stop and reconnect spring rabbitmq listener containers and their connections?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I've an internet connection where the exit gateway periodically changes. I'm getting an event or callback notification to my spring application some seconds before this happens. I would like to stop my rabbit consumers and connections then and connect again after some seconds (when my network connection is back).

I'm using the annotation based approach of spring amqp but i could also switch to another kind of implementation.

I know that spring-amqp is doing a reconnect for me but i would like to do that by myself to have more control over it.
How can i programmatically do a clean stop of all consumers (RabbitListeners) and also a clean disconnect from rabbitmq broker and again a clean connect and start of all consumers? It would be fine if the consumers would get recreated. If this is not possible i would have to reinitialize some object attributes.

Answer (score 9):

You can `@Autowire` the `RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry` and call `stop()` to stop all the `@RabbitListener` instances.

Then call `resetConnection()` on the connection factory to close the connection.

Restarting the registry will then cause the connection to be re-established.

Comment: I already did this exactly like you described. I used the start() method of the registry to start it again but i'm also getting exceptions while doing this. Is it possible to stop the listener instances directly (interrupt) instead of wating for a clean complete? I don't want them to finish. I'll test it again with your description, maybe i've done something different. Thank you very much.

Comment: The exceptions i'm getting: Channel shutdown: connection error from CachingConnectionFactory

Comment: You can get references to each container from the registry and stop/start them individually, but the container does not currently provide an option to interrupt the listener threads - bear in mind that an interrupt will only actually do anything if the thread does something that's interruptible. You could inject your own `TaskExecutor` into the container factory and shut it down to interrupt the threads. You would need to inject a new one before re-starting, though.

Comment: So it would be enough to just create my own executor on application startup, setTaskExecutor() on the container factory and when i need to handle a network change, get that executor, stop it, recreate it and set it again on the conainter factory. After that i've to start the registry again. Am i right?

Comment: No; just re-injecting into the factory won't work - you need to iterate over each container (the factory has already done it's work and created them) and re-inject the TE into each container.

Comment: Thank you, so i've to iterate over each container, get the taskExecutor, stop it, after network change iterate again over each container and replace the taskExecutor with the new one. I think i've to use the following method: http://docs.spring.io/spring-amqp/api/org/springframework/amqp/rabbit/listener/SimpleMessageListenerContainer.html#setTaskExecutor-java.util.concurrent.Executor- I'll test it.

Comment: You can use a single TE across all containers - that's what will happen when the factory creates them. You need to stop the containers (by stopping the registry or iterating). Then shutdown the executor. Then inject a new (shared) one into each (after initializing the TE), then start the containers.

Comment: I've implemented it like you described it and it seems to work but i'm getting some exception (which don't have impact on functionallity). It seems that this has to do with the underlying rabbitmq connection that stays connected/alive instead beeing shut down. The exception: https://gist.github.com/PatrickHuetter/db83932f8dcceb28e6986a76ca5ba571 The code (short version): https://gist.github.com/PatrickHuetter/5522e4ab63fb5591bc424a1c0f547a47

Comment: Did you call `resetConnection()` on the connection factory after stopping the containers?

Comment: Yes, after calling rabbitListenerEndpointRegistry.stop(); (Which iterates over the containers and stops each of them)

Comment: Sorry - missed that in your code. Hmmm - you might want to try waiting for the executor to shut down after your `shutdownNow()` call - before resetting the connection - let the threads wind down,