# Rabbit SimpleMessageListenerContainer won't shut down

Tags: java, rabbitmq, spring-amqp

Following on from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49155600/detect-and-recover-from-credential-deletion-in-spring-amqp), we have a scenario where Rabbit credentials become invalidated, and we need to call `resetConnection()` on our `CachingConnectionFactory` to pick up a fresh set of credentials.

We're doing this in a `ShutdownSignalException` handler, and it basically works. What doesn't work is that we also need to restart our listeners. We have a few of these:

```
@RabbitListener(
    id = ABC,
    bindings = @QueueBinding(value = @Queue(value="myQ", durable="true"),
        exchange = @Exchange(value="myExchange", durable="true"),
        key = "myKey"),
    containerFactory = "customQueueContainerFactory"
)
public void process(...) {
   ...
}
```

The impression given by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40021038/954442) (also [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42377352/954442)) is that we just need to do:

```
@Autowired RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry;
@Autowired CachingConnectionFactory connectionFactory;

@Override
public void shutdownCompleted(ShutdownSignalException cause) {
    refreshRabbitMQCredentials();
}

public void refreshRabbitMQCredentials() {
    registry.stop();  // do this first

    // Fetch credentials, update username/pass
    connectionFactory.resetConnection(); // then this

    registry.start();  // finally restart
}
```

The problem is that having debugged my way through `SimpleMessageListenerContainer`, when the very first of these containers has `doShutdown()` called, Spring tries to cancel the `BlockingQueueConsumer`.

Because the underlying `Channel` still reports as being open - even though the RabbitMQ UI doesn't report any connections or channels being open - a Cancel event is sent to the broker inside `ChannelN.basicCancel()`, but the channel then blocks forever for a reply, and as a result container shutdown is completely blocked.

I've tried injecting a `TaskExecutor` (a `Executors.newCachedThreadPool()`) into the containers and calling `shutdownNow()` or interrupting them, but none of this affects the channel's blocking wait.

It looks like my only option to unblock the channel is to trigger an additional `ShutdownSignalException` during cancellation, but (a) I don't know how I can do that, and (b) it looks like I would have to initiate cancellation of all listeners in parallel before trying to shutdown again).

```
// com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN
@Override
public void basicCancel(final String consumerTag) throws IOException
{
    // [snip]

    rpc(new Basic.Cancel(consumerTag, false), k);

    try {
        k.getReply(); // <== BLOCKS HERE
    } catch(ShutdownSignalException ex) {
        throw wrap(ex);
    }
    metricsCollector.basicCancel(this, consumerTag);
}
```

I'm not sure why this is proving so difficult. Is there a simpler way to force `SimpleMessageListenerContainer` shutdown?

---

Using Spring Rabbit 1.7.6; AMQP Client 4.0.3; Spring Boot 1.5.10-RELEASE

---

**UPDATE**

Some logs to demonstrate the theory that the message containers are restarting before connection refresh has completed, and that this might be why they don't reconnect:

```
ERROR o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Channel shutdown: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue 'amq.gen-4-bqGxbLio9mu8Kc7MMexw' in vhost '/' refused for user 'cert-configserver-feb6e103-76a8-f5bf-3f23-1e8150812bc4', class-id=50, method-id=10)
INFO  u.c.c.c.r.ReauthenticatingChannelListener - Channel shutdown: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue 'amq.gen-4-bqGxbLio9mu8Kc7MMexw' in vhost '/' refused for user 'cert-configserver-feb6e103-76a8-f5bf-3f23-1e8150812bc4', class-id=50, method-id=10)
INFO  u.c.c.c.r.ReauthenticatingChannelListener - Channel closed with reply code 403. Assuming credentials have been revoked and refreshing config server properties to get new credentials. Cause: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue 'amq.gen-4-bqGxbLio9mu8Kc7MMexw' in vhost '/' refused for user 'cert-configserver-feb6e103-76a8-f5bf-3f23-1e8150812bc4', class-id=50, method-id=10)
WARN  u.c.c.c.r.ReauthenticatingChannelListener - Shutdown signalled: com.rabbitmq.client.ShutdownSignalException: channel error; protocol method: #method<channel.close>(reply-code=403, reply-text=ACCESS_REFUSED - access to queue 'amq.gen-4-bqGxbLio9mu8Kc7MMexw' in vhost '/' refused for user 'cert-configserver-feb6e103-76a8-f5bf-3f23-1e8150812bc4', class-id=50, method-id=10)
INFO  u.c.c.c.r.RabbitMQReauthenticator - Refreshing Rabbit credentials for XXXXXXXX
INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Fetching config from server at: http://localhost:8888/configuration
INFO  u.c.c.c.r.ReauthenticatingChannelListener - Got ListenerContainerConsumerFailedEvent: Consumer raised exception, attempting restart
INFO  o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer - Restarting Consumer@2db55dec: tags=[{amq.ctag-ebAfSnXLbw_W1hlZ5ag7sQ=consumer.myQ}], channel=Cached Rabbit Channel: AMQChannel(amqp://cert-configserver-feb6e103-76a8-f5bf-3f23-1e8150812bc4@127.0.0.1:5672/,2), conn: Proxy@12de62aa Shared Rabbit Connection: SimpleConnection@56c95789 [delegate=amqp://cert-configserver-feb6e103-76a8-f5bf-3f23-1e8150812bc4@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 50052], acknowledgeMode=AUTO local queue size=0
INFO  o.s.c.c.c.ConfigServicePropertySourceLocator - Located environment: name=myApp, profiles=[default], label=null, version=null, state=null
INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - XXXXXXXX - Shutdown initiated...
INFO  com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource - XXXXXXXX - Shutdown completed.
INFO  u.c.c.c.r.RabbitMQReauthenticator - Refreshed username: 'cert-configserver-feb6e103-76a8-f5bf-3f23-1e8150812bc4' => 'cert-configserver-d7b54af2-0735-a9ed-7cc4-394803bf5e58'
INFO  u.c.c.c.r.RabbitMQReauthenticator - CachingConnectionFactory reset, proceeding...
```

---

**UPDATE 2:**

This does seem to be a race condition of sorts. Having removed the container stop / starts, if I add a thread-only breakpoint to `SimpleMessageListenerContainer.restart()` to let the `resetConnection()` race past, and then release the breakpoint, then I can see things start to come back:

```
16:18:47,208 INFO  u.c.c.c.r.RabbitMQReauthenticator - CachingConnectionFactory reset
// Get ready to release the SMLC.restart() breakpoint...
16:19:02,072 INFO  o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Attempting to connect to: rabbitmq.service.consul:5672
16:19:02,083 INFO  o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory - Created new connection: connectionFactory#7489bca4:1/SimpleConnection@68546c13 [delegate=amqp://cert-configserver-132a07c2-94f3-0099-4de1-f0b1a9875d5a@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 33350]
16:19:02,086 INFO  o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin - Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue ...
16:19:02,095 DEBUG u.c.c.c.r.ReauthenticatingChannelListener - Active connection check succeeded for channel AMQChannel(amqp://cert-configserver-132a07c2-94f3-0099-4de1-f0b1a9875d5a@127.0.0.1:5672/,1)
16:19:02,120 INFO  o.s.amqp.rabbit.core.RabbitAdmin - Auto-declaring a non-durable, auto-delete, or exclusive Queue (springCloudBus...
```

That being the case I now have to work out either how to delay the container restarts until the refresh is done (i.e. my `ShutdownSignalException` handler completes), or make the refresh blocking somehow...

---

**UPDATE 3:**

My overall problem, of which this was a symptom, was solved with: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49392990/954442

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not at all clear why the channel would report as open; this works fine for me; it recovers after deleting user `foo`...

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class So49323291Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So49323291Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public ApplicationRunner runner(RabbitListenerEndpointRegistry registry, CachingConnectionFactory cf,
            RabbitTemplate template) {
        return args -> {
            cf.setUsername("foo");
            cf.setPassword("bar");
            registry.start();
            doSends(template);
            registry.stop();
            cf.resetConnection();
            cf.setUsername("baz");
            cf.setPassword("qux");
            registry.start();
            doSends(template);
        };
    }

    public void doSends(RabbitTemplate template) {
        while (true) {
            try {
                template.convertAndSend("foo", "Hello");
                Thread.sleep(5_000);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "foo", autoStartup = "false")
    public void in(Message in) {
        System.out.println(in);
    }

}
```

> (Body:'Hello' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=foo, deliveryTag=4, consumerTag=amq.ctag-9zt3wUGYSJmoON3zw03wUw, consumerQueue=foo])
>
> 2018-03-16 11:24:01.451 ERROR 11867 --- [ 127.0.0.1:5672] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Channel shutdown: connection error; protocol method: #method(reply-code=320, reply-text=CONNECTION_FORCED - user 'foo' is deleted, class-id=0, method-id=0)
>
> ...
>
> Caused by: com.rabbitmq.client.AuthenticationFailureException: ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism PLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.
>
> 2018-03-16 11:24:01.745 ERROR 11867 --- [cTaskExecutor-2] o.s.a.r.l.SimpleMessageListenerContainer : Stopping container from aborted consumer
>
> 2018-03-16 11:24:03.740  INFO 11867 --- [cTaskExecutor-3] o.s.a.r.c.CachingConnectionFactory       : Created new connection: rabbitConnectionFactory#2c4d1ac:3/SimpleConnection@5e9c036b [delegate=amqp://baz@127.0.0.1:5672/, localPort= 59346]
>
> (Body:'Hello' MessageProperties [headers={}, contentType=text/plain, contentEncoding=UTF-8, contentLength=0, receivedDeliveryMode=PERSISTENT, priority=0, redelivered=false, receivedExchange=, receivedRoutingKey=foo, deliveryTag=1, consumerTag=amq.ctag-ljnY00TBuvy5cCAkpD3r4A, consumerQueue=foo])

However, you really don't need to stop/start the registry, just reconfigure the connection factory with the new credentials and call `resetConnection()`; the containers will recover.

Comment: Thanks. I hoped I wouldn't have to do the stop/start but the containers don't recover either way. I wondered if it might be because the consumer restarts before the `CachingConnectionFactory` has had its credentials set. Also, if I lower the Spring AMQP logging to DEBUG it still seems to be fetching with the old details. There doesn't seem to be any kind of 'reset' going on there.

Comment: Seems to be a race condition affecting me but not you.

Comment: I tested with 2.0.2 but I don't recall any changes that would affect this. I'll try with 1.7.x next week. Do you see different behavior if you set `possibleAuthenticationFailureFatal` on the container to `false`?

Comment: Thanks for looking. Tested and that flag has no effect here. It really looks like a dislocation between the containers and the `ShutdownSignalException` handler: only if I can share some state between the threads can I try to reorder the refresh before the container restarts...

Comment: I just tested with 1.7.6 with no problems; if you can put together a small example that exhibits the problem, I will figure out what's wrong.

Comment: OK. For the time being I'm using a copy/paste of SimpleMessageListenerContainer with a 2 second sleep inserted before the `restart()` call, and that just about works.

Comment: Thanks, Gary. This is all good advice so I'll accept even though I was probably on the wrong track. My overall problem was solved with https://stackoverflow.com/a/49392990/954442